# Is there a way to distinguish different network types in ConnectionManager

Tags: android

I've been using NetworkInfo, since its deprecated in API 29, so I'd to move on to ConnectionManager. I've followed the documentation as [mentioned here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback.html) & [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities)

But I can't make out how to distinguish between different modes of network

This is how I implented

```
void getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
        manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI).build();
        }
    }

    //Register and unregister network callbacks

    @Override
    public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network){
        super.onAvailable(network);
            Status = TYPE_MOBILE;
            //TODO: Different modes of network
            //Status = TYPE_WIFI;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLost(@NonNull Network network){
        super.onLost(network);
        Status = TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }
```

Earlier I was using getNetworkInfo, but its deprecated, is there any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `ConnectivityManager#getNetworkCapabilities(network: Network?)`?

```java
    @Override
    public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network){
        super.onAvailable(network);

        NetworkCapabilities nc = manager.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
        if (nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
            // connected to a cellular network
        } else if (nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
            // connected to a wifi network
        }
        // add more if you need to!
    }
```